# How to copy data from One Excel sheet to another sheet for same Workbook Using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I specifically am trying to copy certain cells from one sheet in Excel workbook, and paste them into certain cells in  same Excel workbook for differnt sheet. How to copy the stored contents into a particular sheet, in another sheet for same workbook.I have two sheets in first sheet data and values are mentioned in below input. Then in second sheet for same excel get values only for the particular header. Any clue how I may go about this? Also, is it possible to make the range defined for a CellRange conditional on certain cell properties?

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you, all.

Below Input are in Sheet1
**Input**
|Student ID| Student Name| Java| Python| OS | .NET| DBMS| C | C++ | VB | Practical 1 | Practical 2| Total| Average|

|1     | Anu     | 100 | 80    | 70 | 60  | 85  | 74| 60  |100 | 90      | 89     | 808  | 80.8   |

|2     | Bala    | 100 | 100   | 100| 70  | 70  | 80| 80  | 90 | 90      | 100    | 880  | 88     |

|3     | Chitra  | 80  | 70    | 40 | 60  | 50  | 45| 55  | 65 | 70      | 80     | 615  | 61.5   |

**Output**

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to transform data as you need and store it another sheet :

```
#Columns in student.xlsx : Name,Gender,DOB,Maths,Physics,Chemistry,English,Biology,Economics,History,Civics
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel(open('student.xlsx', 'rb'),
              sheet_name='Sheet1')
af = df.melt(id_vars="Name","Gender","DOB"],var_name="Subject",value_name="Marks")
result  = af.sort_values(by="Name")
result.to_excel('student.xlsx,sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

Comment: In second sheet having a template format, i need to get the  values in second sheet for respective column hedaers. Example : Student ID : 1. I dont want to paste the same thing from first to second sheet.My second sheet looks like above output format

Comment: Thanks @YeshSurya, its working. Is it possible to use macros in python? I need to use macros in this case.

Comment: It seems possible. You can refer here : https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/macros.html#:~:text=Macros%20From%20Excel-,Introduction,you%20use%20the%20xl_macro%20decorator.